# uiview don't accept touch after move animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

i have a uiview position below the UIviewController bounds
and i'm animating it's appearance from bottom to top (like actionsheet)

```
- (IBAction)Button:(id)sender {

   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
   [_pickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, self.view.frame.size.height - _pickerView.frame.size.height , 0.0f, 0.0f)];
   [UIView commitAnimations];   
}
```

the poblem that after the uiview appear no user interaction with view avilable
what i'm missing ?

Comment: Set view.userInteractionEnabled=YES; to your view.

Comment: i tried serInteractionEnabled=YES it don't work

Comment: present your _pickerView width=height=0.0 so set width, height for your _pickerView now it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `frame` of your `view` has no width or height. Most likely your components are still appearing because your view doesn't "clip subviews."

Your code:

```
[_pickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, self.view.frame.size.height - _pickerView.frame.size.height , 0.0f, 0.0f)];
//  0.0f, 0.0f <-- width and height.
```

The result is, you can see the elements, but not interact with them. When I think I've done this, I set the background color of my view so I can see the frame visially.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6f];
[_pickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(@"As U Want")];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

`[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6f];` this line is very important :)